# vim splits behave weird with explorer

Tags: vim

So this is straightforward to reproduce, it's just that I'm not sure if it's a bug.

```
C-w v # to split vertically
:Ex   # open explorer in current split
C-w l # switch to the other split
:Ex   # open explorer

      # at this point, cursor went back to the first split

Enter # open file in the current split
```

At this point, I cannot switch to the other split where Explorer is active/visible. However, if I do `:q` to close the first split, Explorer becomes active.

Is this a bug?

Comment: I can't reproduce this; what version/variant of vim are you using? NetRW (the built-in plugin that provides ":Ex") is *really* buggy, though, so my bet would be this is a bug... perhaps interacting with your vimrc in some way; can you reproduce by running vim without loading your configs?

Comment: I use the one in Homebrew, `:version` outputs 7.4 with included patches 1-979. `:let g:loaded_netrwPlugin` says v154.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this seems to be a bug as mentioned [here](https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar/issues/58). [@zenazn](https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar/issues/58#issuecomment-169212924) suggests that it's fixed in v155 (alpha?).